# Prove that if all triangles have the same angle sum then the sum of the angles in any triangle must be 180.

Tags: geometry

I don't know where to start.

I know that the sum of the angles is less than or equal to 180. 
but how do i prove this.

Comment: Hint: find an example.

Comment: Hagen von Eitzen has posted and elegant solution, but one that does not directly address what seems to be the question.  I'll post a separate question so that he can post that answer to it.

Answer (score 3):

Let the sum be $x$. Cut an arbitrary triangle into two triangles. The sum of the smaller triangles is $2x$ but also $x+180^\circ$.

Comment: This is elegant, but it seems to be an attempt to prove the general result rather than to answer the question in the way in which it was asked.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't get your point. My method solves the task in the OP title. I interprete the body text as solution attempts and do not think that it is intended that one shows that the angle sum is $\le 180^\circ$ (which would allow hyperbolic, but disallow elliptic geometry; the title claim (in its "if then" formulation) is true in all three geometries.

Comment: The way the problem is phrased makes me think that what was intended was this: Find one triangle for which it is easy to show that the sum is $180^\circ$, then conclude that if all triangles have the SAME angle sum, then they're all $180^\circ$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

It seems what must have been intended is this: Find *one* triangle in which it is easy to prove that the sum is $180^\circ$.

Then deduce that if it's the same in all other triangles, then it must be $180^\circ$ in all triangles.

**PS:** OK, let's look at the isosceles right triangle.  The **conventional** way to view it would say that since one angle is $90^\circ$ and the other two are equal to each other, and the sum of all three must be $180^\circ$, it follows that the sum of those two must be $90^\circ$, so each must be $45^\circ$.  **But** we cannot do that here because the fact that the sum is $180^\circ$ is what we must **prove** rather than a fact that we can rely on in this context.  So here's what I propose: Draw the diagonal of a square, dividing it into two triangles of the shape just described.  The diagonal splits the $90^\circ$ angle at one corner of the square into two parts.  Argue that those two parts are congruent, so each must be half of $90^\circ$.  Then you have the two $45^\circ$ angles, so the sum is proved to be $180^\circ$.

Finally, if the sum must be the same in all triangles, then $180^\circ$ is it.

Comment: Actually I wonder whether whoever posed this problem realized it would have such a solution. (It is a good solution nevertheless.)

Comment: Hm, finding an example requires to show that certain figures, e.g. rectangles or regular hexagons, exist, doesn't it?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen : You only need the existence of the isosceles right triangle, with two $45^\circ$ angles.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a generic triangle. Produce a line through a vertex parallel to the opposite side. Applying alternate angles, the result is seen.